# How to initialize static attribute with class attribute

Tags: java, static

I wonder if the following implementation is correct or if there is something simpler to do. My idea is to call the method to initialize the static attribute only once. Since the initialization method needs the id attribute, I guess I have to do it in the constructor.

```
public class A {

   private int              id;
   private static Point2D[] myArray = new Point2D[10];

   public A(int id) {
      this.id = id;
      if (myArray[0] == null) { // I want the array to be initialized only once.
         initArray(id);
      }
   }

   private static void initArray(int id) {
      for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
         myArray[i] = new Point2D(id, id);
      }
   }

}
```

Comment: You want to initialize a static array based on the non-static `id`? Why so?

Comment: Since you need the first `id`, you are doing it right. Not sure why you do that but that's syntaxicaly correct.

Comment: Can you explain what you are going to do with those `Point2D` with the same values ? Are you just instanciating "blank" `Point2D` to use them later on ? Based on the need, this could be done differently. But the question is too broad to give a complete answer.

Comment: @AxelH Actually this isn't the code that I'm using, it was just to post a simple example without useless informations

Comment: You did well, this is a good question. I just want to let you know that this simple example is valid but based on the context (the need for that array), it could change some thing. So if you can keep that example simple but show the need behind, this could change the result. What are you going to do with those instances ?

Comment: Alright so here's the context. I receive a polygon (an array of Point2D). From this polygon, I calculate the 4 corners of the smallest Rectangle (2 points with width and height are actually sufficient enough but whatever) in which the polygon fits (bottom left corner will be minX and minY and top right corner will be maxX and maxY). Since all my instances need to know theses corners, I made this array of corners static.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good to me. As you have made static members private, so only way it can be set in constructor or in any other method by passing the variable and having a check condition. Static initializer won't work as it runs before constructor, and you won't get **ID** till then.

Answer (score -1):

The object *myArray* is actually initialized only once, that is when you call the `new` operator, and you can't push values in this object because the variable *id* is not `final` (and `static`).

Probably ask to yourself if you really need this class and which are the responsibilities of it.

Comment: This is completely wrong. Indeed, myArray is initialized only once. This doesn't mean that I can't push values into it, no matter whether id is final or static (which is not the case in the code I posted).

Comment: The array is initialized during the class loading, not during the constructor. The array is filled with instanced during the first instanciation of a `A` instance.